# Why doesn't Clover always report code coverage for my Java web app?

Tags: java, code-coverage, clover

I am using clover code coverage for finding the code coverage. I have instrumented my code and placed it as dependency in my web project.

Sometimes my clover db gets updated sometimes it does not. Why?  Is there any bug in Clover tool?

I am using Clover and my code is in Java.

Sometimes I see separate file created in the directory where my cloverdb is placed. Sometimes those files are not created.  At what interval those files are created?

Answer (score 0):

Clover only runs tests on code that has changed since the last time tests were run. See [this post on Clover's test optimization](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2008/11/stop_testing_so_much/).

Have you changed code under test?  It could be that when the db is not updated you haven't changed any code that there are tests for.

Comment: @Paul.I have created a new db.So it should  run test on entire code right?Also am running test case seperately.Meaning when my server is up , we fire testcase remotely.Like firing http requests.Also out test cases are written using silk test are executed using browser

Comment: @Paul.Can you please give me with this?I just need to put my jar along with clover.jar and clover license with the lib directry right?

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes I see separate file created in the directory where my cloverdb is placed. Sometimes those files are not created. At what interval those files are created?

You mentioned that you have a web project. In case when project runs on an application server and you don't have the 'threaded' or 'interval' flush policy set **and** you don't shut down the server at the end of tests, then the coverage file will not be produced, because by default it happens at the JVM termination.

See:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+Clover+for+web+applications